# ubuntu/ros error

Tags: ros, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros hydro and have been using it correctly. BUt after some days, I got a problem. Now whenever I open a terminal, it says:

bash: /home/mudassar/ros/setup.sh: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Could anyone help to resolve my issue? Is there some problem in my .bashrc file? Please be detailed as I am very new to ubuntu and ros.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125286/ubuntu/ros-error/) by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are sourcing `/opt/ros/electric/setup.bash` in your bashrc, but you have hydro installed. Change electric for hydro.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on 2014-02-01**:
I have again run

"source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash"

but for the next time when I start terminal, the same message appears as before.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-01**:
You should update this in your .bashrc, where you originally put the electric entry.

**Comment by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on 2014-02-01**:
Please guide how can I update it? I am very new to ubuntu or ros. Which commands should I execute in terminal to update my bashrc for hydro?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-01**:
Just edit the .bashrc in your home with any text editor that you like. You should find a line in there containing electric.

**Comment by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on 2014-02-01**:
Thankyou very much! Issue Resolved!